# Can a single class be used like this?

Tags: c#, oop

I have data to be stored to a file. The data is as below:

```
    {
       "student": {
                      "FirstName": {
                                     "Initial": "Mr.",
                                     "Value": "Luis"
                                   },
                     "MiddleName": {
                                     "Initial": "Mr.",
                                     "Value": "Bruce"
                                   },
                       "LastName": "Wayne"
                 }
    }
```

I retrieve the data from the file into a class Student:

```
     public class Student
    {
        public FirstName Firstname {get;set;}
        public MiddleName Middlename {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
    }

    public class FirstName
   {
       public string Initial {get;set;}
       public string Value {get;set;}
   }
    public class MiddleName
   {
       public string Initial {get;set;}
       public string Value {get;set;}
   }
```

My question is: **Can I build a class as given below to store the same info?**

```
     public class Student
    {
        public NameClass Firstname {get;set;}
        public NameClass Middlename {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
    }

    public class NameClass
   {
       public string Initial {get;set;}
       public string Value {get;set;}
   }
```

Is it the right approach? or my previous approach is better?

Comment: Why the C++ tag? You are showing C# code.

Comment: Got to love a question about Batman being edited by Iron Man.

Comment: @Rawling:..Failed to get you?

Comment: Well, your question's about Batman, right? And it's been edited by a guy whose icon is Iron Man?

Comment: @Rawling:...hahahaha...now got that...:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it works pretty well...Following class structure is optimized

```
public class Student
 {
    public NameClass Firstname {get;set;}
    public NameClass Middlename {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
 }

 public class NameClass
{
   public string Initial {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't see any problem, with that.

Actually it's definitely better, then was done before, as you unify common information in one single class.

The only thing, that comes to my mind, is that you have to revise your serialization `to` and `from`,as you change classes architecture.